# How to model this(in the image provided) in solidworks

Tags: solidworks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsPSv.jpg)
How can I model this in solidworks. The text can be created using the text feature in sketch.But how to get the outline as in this image:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a sketch offset. This question is best suited for the [SOLIDWORKS forums](https://forum.solidworks.com/community/solidworks).